# ¿Como evitar recargar un activity o sus procedimientos cuando se ingresa nuevamente a ella?

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un problema con mi APP y no se como solucionarlo, me colaboran por favor.

Cuando abro mi APP se ejecuta bien, sin problemas, incluso ejecuta bien la clase formado_palabras().

El problema inicia cuando voy a otra activity y vuelvo, se recarga la activity inicial y la clase formando_palabras(), he notado que la clase formando_palabras() se ejecuta tantas veces como regrese a la activity principal. Me doy cuenta de ello porque la clase formando_plabras(), genera un sonido cada vez que se arma una palabra, y ahora resulta que el sonido se repite simultáneamente las mismas veces que reingreso a la activity principal.

Existe alguna forma de evitar que se recargue cada vez que vuelvo a la activity principal, gracias

El código de mi APP en su activity principal es el siguiente

```
public class principal extends AppCompatActivity {

Button boton_1, boton_2, boton_3;
TextView palabra_nueva, numero_palabras;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    boton_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_1);
    boton_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_2);
    boton_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_3);

    palabra_nueva = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.palabra_nueva);
    numero_palabras = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numero_palabras);

    formando_palabras();

 }

}
```

Comment: Hay una cosa que se llama [ciclo de vida de una actividad](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle?hl=es) y que te permitiría entender por qué eso sucede. Verás, cada vez que abres una activity, el método *onCreate* vuelve a ejecutarse! Las activity por si mismas no tienen *persistencia*, así que cada vez que vuelves a una, se recarga entera :) Si quieres que algo permanezca entre activities, debes guardarlo *fuera* de la activity!

Comment: @Benito-B gracias por responder, ya entiendo, una pregunta, ¿existe alguna forma de verificar si alguna clase o procedimiento se esta ejecutando? Saludos

Comment: @Isabel es esta la pregunta que comentabas?

Comment: @Jorgesys Si señor, lo que deseo es que no se reinicie formando_palabras() si ya esta corriendo cuando regreso al activity principal desde otra activity. Algo así como if formando_palabras() { ... No se como hacerlo, me colabora por favor

Comment: @Jorgesys buenas tardes, que pena molestarlo nuevamente, si existe alguna forma de verificar lo que preguntaba la semana pasada?

Comment: Perdón Isabel, estaba muy ocupado olvide esta pregunta, ¿Solo quieres se ejecute cuando cargas una vez la Activity y nunca más o cuando quieres se vuelve a llamar formando_palabras() ? @Isabel

Comment: @Jorgesys gracias, lo que quiero y no he podido, es poder verificar si formando_palabras() se esta ejecutando o no cuando abro el activity, algo así como if (formando_palabras()) { formando_palabras() }    Esto es con el fin, de que si se esta ejecutando, no se ejecute nuevamente, y sino se esta ejecutando se ejecute.

Comment: @Isabel ok entonces formando_palabras() es un Thread, que es, podrías agregar que realiza por favor?

Comment: @Jorgesys tanto como un Thread no, formando_palabras() es un método de una clase, este método a su vez ejecuta otra clase llamada letras. Lo que he tratado de validar y no he podido es, si el método formando_palabras() o la clase letras se están ejecutando

Comment: @Isabel agregalo por favor Isabe!!